# VSCode- exclude specific folder/file from IntelliSense parsing

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have an issue with C/C++ intelliSense parsing. When the function declaration described in one file and the same name is used for typedef in another file.
Explanation:
Image we have next structure of folders and files:

[image: Files Structure]

file dir1/f1.h contains:

```
typedef int func1;
```

file dir2/f1.h contains:

```
void func1(void);
```

file dir2/f1.c contains:

```
#include "f1.h"

void func1(void) {
   // do something
}
```

file main.c contains:

```
#include "f1.h"

int main(void) {
    func1();
}
```

When I use command go to definition, the IntelliSense goes to the dir1/f1.h file because the last open file was dir1/f1.h. If the last opened file was  dir2/f1.h the IntelliSense will jump to  dir2/f1.h or dir2/f1.c.

I am wondering how to exclude dir1 or dir1/f1.h from IntelliSense parsing but not from workspace and searching results? So I need next:

- IntelliSense ignore/do not parse dir1 or dir1/f1.h
- dir1 and dir1/f1.h present in workspace view
- searcher do not ignore dir1/f1.h

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm rewriting some code and like to have the old code visible for reference, but if I leave it in the same root directory (with dependency libraries, etc) intellisense does all kinds of crazy stuff with includes even if it's up a couple directories from the files I'm working with. I'd love to exclude it from Intellisense but still be able to access and view the files in the same workspace. (At the moment I put it in a separate root dir and just run two windows, but that's suboptimal.)

Comment: Hi @dwllama, I did not find answer or any convenient workaround. I think I need to create a feature ticket in vscode github community.